# Dropdown list not appearing in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a dropdown component in react but the list doesn't appear when i click the button. i've tried gpt's but its not helping. following are the three jsx files that are using the code.

DropdownList.jsx

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function DropdownList({ listLength, handleOptionSelect, dropdownliname }) {
    const listItems = Array.from({ length: listLength }, (_, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
            <a
                className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600"
                href="#"
                data-te-dropdown-item-ref
                onClick={() => handleOptionSelect(index)}
            >
                {dropdownliname(index + 1)}
            </a>
        </li>
    ));

    return (
        <ul
            className="absolute z-[1000] float-left m-0 hidden min-w-max list-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-none bg-white bg-clip-padding text-left text-base shadow-lg dark:bg-neutral-700 [&[data-te-dropdown-show]]:block"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
            data-te-dropdown-menu-ref
        >
            {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
}

DropdownList.propTypes = {
    listLength: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    handleOptionSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    dropdownliname: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default DropdownList;
```

DropdownButton.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown, Ripple, initTE } from "tw-elements";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import DropdownList from "./DropdownList";

initTE({ Dropdown, Ripple });

function DropdownButton(props) {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
    const [dropdownListLength, setDropdownListLength] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDropdownListLength(parseInt(props.dropdownlistLength, 10));
    }, [props.dropdownlistLength]); // Update dropdownListLength on prop change

    const handleOptionSelect = (optionId) => {
        setSelectedOption(optionId);
    };

    const dropdownliname = (index) => props[`dropdownliname${index}`];

    const buttonColorClass =
        selectedOption !== null ? "text-black" : "text-gray-400";

    return (
        <div className="relative" data-te-dropdown-ref>
            <label
                htmlFor={props.dropdownlabelhtmlfor}
                className="mb-4 px-1 text-sm text-start font-medium text-grey-900"
            >
                {props.dropdownlabelname}
            </label>
            <button
                className={`flex items-center justify-between text-end w-full px-3 py-2 mt-2 mb-4 text-sm border-2 border-black rounded-lg focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none ${buttonColorClass}`}
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                data-te-dropdown-toggle-ref
                aria-expanded="false"
                data-te-ripple-init
                data-te-ripple-color="light"
            >
                {selectedOption !== null
                    ? dropdownliname(selectedOption + 1)
                    : props.dropdownbuttonname}
                <span className="mr-2 w-2">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="h-5 w-5"
                    >
                        <path
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                            d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
                            clipRule="evenodd"
                        />
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </button>
            {dropdownListLength && (
                <DropdownList
                    listLength={dropdownListLength}
                    handleOptionSelect={handleOptionSelect}
                    dropdownliname={dropdownliname}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

DropdownButton.propTypes = {
    dropdownbuttonname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    dropdownlabelname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    dropdownlabelhtmlfor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    dropdownlistLength: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

Array.from(
    { length: DropdownButton.propTypes.dropdownlistLength },
    (_, index) => {
        DropdownButton.propTypes[`dropdownliname${index + 1}`] =
            PropTypes.string.isRequired;
    }
);

export default DropdownButton;
```

BusinessRegistrationForm.jsx

```
import Button from "./Button";
import DropdownButton from "./DropdownButton";
import InputField from "./InputField";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

function BusinessRegistrationForm() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center py-36">
                <div className="flex justify-center py-12">
                    <div className="w-[590px]">
                        <h3 className="pb-6 text-center text-4xl font-extrabold text-dark-grey-900">
                            Let us know more <br />
                            about your business.
                        </h3>
                        {/* <div className="mt-6">
                            <h1 className="text-black">Select type of account</h1>

                            <div className="mt-3 md:flex md:items-center md:-mx-2">
                                <button className="flex justify-center w-full px-6 py-3 text-black rounded-md md:w-auto md:mx-2 focus:outline-none">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        className="w-6 h-6"
                                        fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                        strokeWidth="2"
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            strokeLinecap="round"
                                            strokeLinejoin="round"
                                            d="M21 13.255A23.931 23.931 0 0112 15c-3.183 0-6.22-.62-9-1.745M16 6V4a2 2 0 00-2-2h-4a2 2 0 00-2 2v2m4 6h.01M5 20h14a2 2 0 002-2V8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2z"
                                        />
                                    </svg>

                                    <span className="mx-2">client</span>
                                </button>

                                <button className="flex justify-center w-full px-6 py-3 mt-4 text-black border border-blue-500 rounded-md md:mt-0 md:w-auto md:mx-2 focus:outline-none">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        className="w-6 h-6"
                                        fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                        strokeWidth="2"
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            strokeLinecap="round"
                                            strokeLinejoin="round"
                                            d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z"
                                        />
                                    </svg>

                                    <span className="mx-2">worker</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div> */}
                        <form>
                            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-4 mt-8 md:grid-cols-2">
                                <div>
                                    <InputField
                                        inputfieldid="businessname"
                                        inputfieldtype="text"
                                        inputfieldplaceholder="John & Sons"
                                        inputfieldhtmlfor="businessname"
                                        inputfieldlabelname="Registered Name"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <InputField
                                        inputfieldid="businesscity"
                                        inputfieldtype="text"
                                        inputfieldplaceholder="Islamabad"
                                        inputfieldhtmlfor="businesscity"
                                        inputfieldlabelname="City"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <InputField
                                        inputfieldid="businesscontactnumber"
                                        inputfieldtype="text"
                                        inputfieldplaceholder="XXXX-XXXXXXX"
                                        inputfieldhtmlfor="businesscontactnumber"
                                        inputfieldlabelname="Contact Number"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <InputField
                                        inputfieldid="businessemail"
                                        inputfieldtype="email"
                                        inputfieldplaceholder="johnsnow@example.com"
                                        inputfieldhtmlfor="businessemail"
                                        inputfieldlabelname="Work Email"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <DropdownButton
                                        dropdownbuttonname="select range"
                                        dropdownlabelname="No. of Employees"
                                        dropdownlistLength={3}
                                        dropdownlabelhtmlfor="employeesno"
                                        dropdownliname0="1 - 5"
                                        dropdownliname1="5 - 10"
                                        dropdownliname2="10 - 15"
                                        dropdownliname3="15 - 20"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <InputField
                                        inputfieldid="businesscategory"
                                        inputfieldtype="text"
                                        inputfieldplaceholder="e.g. IT, Marketing, etc."
                                        inputfieldhtmlfor="businesscategory"
                                        inputfieldlabelname="Field of Work"
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <DropdownButton
                                        dropdownbuttonname="public, private"
                                        dropdownlabelname="Business Type"
                                        dropdownlistLength={5}
                                        dropdownlabelhtmlfor="businesstype"
                                        dropdownliname1="Public Business"
                                        dropdownliname0="Public Business 0"
                                        dropdownliname2="Private Business"
                                        dropdownliname3="Private Business 3"
                                        dropdownliname4="Public Business 4"
                                        dropdownliname5="Private Business 5"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pb-2 px-24">
                                <Button buttonname="add business" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BusinessRegistrationForm;
```

The code provided above is all the code that is linked with the dropdown button component. When I change some code, it works but when the page is refreshed or the page is accessed again, it stops working.

Below is the link for the codesandbox of the code provided:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-list-error-vcjqsn?file=/src/index.js

Comment: This will be cumbersome to replicate in SO's snippet functionality, can you share a CodePen (or similar) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I'll provide a link soon.

Comment: @Harrison https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-list-error-vcjqsn?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there was only a couple of issue that was causing the behaviour...

The main ones were:

- `hidden` was added to the `ul` element which meant it was always hidden

  - to tackle this, I added some state in the `DropdownButton` component to control the open/closed state when clicking the button
  - you may want to expand this to include listening for the user to click outside the dropdown (such as a [useOnClickOutside](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-on-click-outside) hook
- The z-index wasn't (at least not in the sandbox) working so the list was showing behind others at times (wider screens), so I set that to `z-10` instead of z-[1000] as that's a low value in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index), and I personally dislike big values of `z-index` after reading [this article](https://www.codegram.com/blog/stop-ab-using-z-index/)

[Here's the working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-list-error-forked-fxkdgj?file=/src/DropdownList.jsx)

Below you can see the added state in `DropdownButton` for whether the list is open or not:

```js
// DropdownButton.jsx
// 

function DropdownButton(props) {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  const [dropdowListOpen, setDropdowListOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownListLength, setDropdownListLength] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDropdownListLength(parseInt(props.dropdownlistLength, 10));
  }, [props.dropdownlistLength]); // Update dropdownListLength on prop change

  const handleOptionSelect = (optionId) => {
    setSelectedOption(optionId);
    setDropdowListOpen(false);
  };

  const dropdownliname = (index) => props[`dropdownliname${index}`];

  const buttonColorClass =
    selectedOption !== null ? "text-black" : "text-gray-400";

  return (
    <div className="relative" data-te-dropdown-ref>
      <label
        htmlFor={props.dropdownlabelhtmlfor}
        className="mb-4 px-1 text-sm text-start font-medium text-grey-900"
      >
        {props.dropdownlabelname}
      </label>
      <button
        className={`flex items-center justify-between text-end w-full px-3 py-2 mt-2 mb-4 text-sm border-2 border-black rounded-lg focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none ${buttonColorClass}`}
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton1"
        data-te-dropdown-toggle-ref
        aria-expanded="false"
        data-te-ripple-init
        data-te-ripple-color="light"
        onClick={() => setDropdowListOpen(true)}
      >
        {selectedOption !== null
          ? dropdownliname(selectedOption + 1)
          : props.dropdownbuttonname}
        <span className="mr-2 w-2">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            className="h-5 w-5"
          >
            <path
              fillRule="evenodd"
              d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
              clipRule="evenodd"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </button>
      {dropdownListLength && (
        <DropdownList
          dropdowListOpen={dropdowListOpen}
          listLength={dropdownListLength}
          handleOptionSelect={handleOptionSelect}
          dropdownliname={dropdownliname}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then it being used by the `DropdownList` component

```js
// DropdownList.jsx
// 

function DropdownList({
  dropdowListOpen,
  listLength,
  handleOptionSelect,
  dropdownliname
}) {
  const listItems = Array.from({ length: listLength }, (_, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <a
        className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600"
        href="#"
        data-te-dropdown-item-ref
        onClick={() => handleOptionSelect(index)}
      >
        {dropdownliname(index + 1)}
      </a>
    </li>
  ));

  const listClassNames = `absolute z-10 float-left m-0 ${
    dropdowListOpen ? "" : "hidden"
  } min-w-max list-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-none bg-white bg-clip-padding text-left text-base shadow-lg dark:bg-neutral-700 [&[data-te-dropdown-show]]:block`;

  return (
    <ul
      className={listClassNames}
      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
      data-te-dropdown-menu-ref
    >
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I'd also note that it may not be semantically wise to use `a` and `ul` for the Dropdown, it's certainly more appropriate to use `select` for dropdowns, but styling them can be a bit difficult. With that said, I would recommend the [React Dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown) library because it handles a lot of the styling for you (even if it has some bloat to it).
But don't let that point deter you, the form itself looks great and the rest of the code is well written too!

Comment: Thanks alot man. I'll look into react-dropdowns. I hadn't heard of it before and dropdowns have always been tricky for me. Also thanks for the compliment. I try my best to  have clean code. If you can point me to some links to help me in dropdowns that'd be great help.